# How to count for each mapped element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Solved - wasn't aware of the useRef hook which helped me track each individual mapped item.

I have a set of results mapped out within a card element. I want to keep a click count for each of those elements, but with a global JS variable, it counts the clicks of all elements if I call that variable on more than one clickable element per session. I have tried to do id.index, adding (id) + index etc but am stumped. How do I properly use the unique id's to track the index for each card? Thanks

```
function onClick(id) {
    let index = 0;
    index++;
    if (index >= 1) {
      dosomething
    } else if (index === 0) {
      dosomethingelse
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since your project is in React, you might want to check out how states work, which are global within a component

Comment: please include some more code

Comment: @PratikWadekar I just need to find a way to incorporate the id being passed as a param with the index I defined to create unique indexes for each mapped item.

Comment: @MartijnVissers Yes I thought about using state to manage this, but it would be the same thing. I am not sure how to create a unique instance for each mapped element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what and how you want to count and onclick events.

Assuming that you need to keep track of clicks on each element/id:
You can use the `useRef` hook and keep it a global object to track the number of clicks per id.

```js
const clicksPerId = useRef({});

function onClick(id) {
   if (!clicksPerId.current[id]) {
       clicksPerId.current[id] = 0;
   }
   clicksPerId.current[id]++;

   // whatever you want to do with the clicks count
}
```

Comment: Sorry about being unclear in my original question. This worked like a charm, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda confused by your question to be honest however for working with arrays in javascript / React maybe you'll find some of these helpful

1. Getting the array length

```js
const MyComponent = () => {

  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([1, 2]);
  
  // find the length of the array
  const getArrayLength = () => {
    return myArray.length;
  }

  return (
    <p>hello there</p>
  )
}
```

2. Doing something with the index of a maped component:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {

  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([1, 2]);
  
  const handleClick = (index) => {
    // do somthing with the index of the el
  };

  return (
    <>
      { myArray.map((el, index) => {
          return (
            <p
              key={index}
              onClick={() => handleClick(index)}
             >
              el number { el }
            </p>
          )
        }) 
      }
    </>
  )
}
```